# Upgrading software in Mac OS X

Tags: macos

When I upgrade a program like iPhoto or Final Cut Pro etc. can I just delete the old one from Applications?

Comment: [Related](http://superuser.com/questions/237506/managing-applications-on-mac-os-x/237509#237509).

Answer (score 2):

The normal upgrade process will typically install a new application over the old one that resides in the Applications folder. So if you've moved some of those programs *from* the Applications folder, the updated copies will the the ones residing there. If it's something like iMovie, where iMovie HD '06 was not overwritten when installing iMovie '08, then yeah, you could just drag the old one to the trash if you don't need it.

Deleting most applications on OS X is just as easy as dragging from the Applications folder to the trash. However, OS X updates typically don't create duplicate applications, so make sure you know what you're dragging!

Answer (score 1):

Upgrades of Apple apps like iPhoto and Final Cut Pro usually happen in-place and don't leave the old copy behind in Applications. So if you delete the copy you see in Applications, you're deleting the only copy of the app in question. So no, in most cases, you don't want to delete that.

If you had renamed or moved your older version of iPhoto or FCP before you did the upgrade, then the new version is probably in the standard location/name and you can safely delete the old version you had put elsewhere.