# How can I uninstall Desktop Manager from my Mac?

Tags: macos, uninstall

Wanting multiple/virtual desktops, I downloaded [Desktop Manager for the Mac](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/12682/desktop-manager). It turns out to be too buggy. Can anyone provide me step by step instructions to uninstall it?

So far I have done the following:

1. Find the process with `ps -ax`
2. Kill the process with `kill -9 pid`
3. Removed the application with `rm -rf applicationName`

However, the application is not being removed. Will someone please help? Here is the output I get after step 3 above.

```
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes/DesktopNamesPrefs.bundle/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/DesktopNamesPrefs.nib: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes/DesktopNamesPrefs.bundle/Contents/Resources/English.lproj: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes/DesktopNamesPrefs.bundle/Contents/Resources/Spanish.lproj/DesktopNamesPrefs.nib/classes.nib: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes/DesktopNamesPrefs.bundle/Contents/Resources/Spanish.lproj/DesktopNamesPrefs.nib/info.nib: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes/DesktopNamesPrefs.bundle/Contents/Resources/Spanish.lproj/DesktopNamesPrefs.nib/keyedobjects.nib: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes/DesktopNamesPrefs.bundle/Contents/Resources/Spanish.lproj/DesktopNamesPrefs.nib/minus.tiff: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes/DesktopNamesPrefs.bundle/Contents/Resources/Spanish.lproj/DesktopNamesPrefs.nib/plus.tiff: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes/DesktopNamesPrefs.bundle/Contents/Resources/Spanish.lproj/DesktopNamesPrefs.nib: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes/DesktopNamesPrefs.bundle/Contents/Resources/Spanish.lproj: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes/DesktopNamesPrefs.bundle/Contents/Resources: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes/DesktopNamesPrefs.bundle/Contents: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes/DesktopNamesPrefs.bundle: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes/HotKeysPreferences.bundle/Contents/Info.plist: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes/HotKeysPreferences.bundle/Contents/MacOS/HotKeysPreferences: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes/HotKeysPreferences.bundle/Contents/MacOS: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes/HotKeysPreferences.bundle/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/HotKeysPrefs.nib/classes.nib: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes/HotKeysPreferences.bundle/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/HotKeysPrefs.nib/info.nib: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes/HotKeysPreferences.bundle/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/HotKeysPrefs.nib/keyedobjects.nib: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes/HotKeysPreferences.bundle/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/HotKeysPrefs.nib: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes/HotKeysPreferences.bundle/Contents/Resources/English.lproj: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes/HotKeysPreferences.bundle/Contents/Resources/hotkeys.png: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes/HotKeysPreferences.bundle/Contents/Resources/Spanish.lproj/HotKeysPrefs.nib/classes.nib: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes/HotKeysPreferences.bundle/Contents/Resources/Spanish.lproj/HotKeysPrefs.nib/info.nib: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes/HotKeysPreferences.bundle/Contents/Resources/Spanish.lproj/HotKeysPrefs.nib/keyedobjects.nib: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes/HotKeysPreferences.bundle/Contents/Resources/Spanish.lproj/HotKeysPrefs.nib: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes/HotKeysPreferences.bundle/Contents/Resources/Spanish.lproj: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes/HotKeysPreferences.bundle/Contents/Resources: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes/HotKeysPreferences.bundle/Contents: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes/HotKeysPreferences.bundle: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/PreferencePanes: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/screenicon.png: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/Spanish.lproj/Localizable.strings: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/Spanish.lproj/MainWindow.nib/classes.nib: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/Spanish.lproj/MainWindow.nib/info.nib: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/Spanish.lproj/MainWindow.nib/keyedobjects.nib: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/Spanish.lproj/MainWindow.nib: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/Spanish.lproj: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources/WorkspaceManagerIcon.icns: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents/Resources: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app/Contents: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1//Desktop Manager.app: Read-only file system
rm: DesktopManager 0.5.4r1/: Resource busy
```

Answer (score 1):

The Desktop Manager download is provided as a read-only disk image you mounted and ran the program from. You did not actually copy it to a persistent installation location on your hard drive. [More about disk images and OS X software distribution in general](https://superuser.com/questions/237506/managing-applications-on-mac-os-x/237509#237509).

Just unmount it by clicking the *eject* button next to it in Finder.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply find the application within your application folder, then right click and delete, as most Mac apps are all packaged within itself this should remove move it all?

Also using the terminal, change the directory to your applications directory:

```
    cd /applications
```

Once the directory os chnaged to your applications delete the selected app.

```
    rm -fR myappname.app
```

This should then remvoe the application.

When using terminal please ensure you understand what you are doing

Comment: Thanks for replying.
I have already done everything you mentioned. The problem is the application is not visible in the /applications directory. I even tried ls -la in the terminal to see if the name showed up: nothing. Perhaps someone has installed and uninstalled Desktop Manager and can share their experience with me.