# how do I source control my color profiles?

Tags: mac, unix, version-control, color-profiles, dotfiles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to keep my OSX settings under version-control ?](https://superuser.com/questions/227211/how-to-keep-my-osx-settings-under-version-control)

I switch between a bunch of Mac and Linux machines at work/home.

On my Personal Mac, I have setup `TextMate`, `iTerm`, `XCode` color profiles that are exactly the way I want them to be. However when I move to a different Mac machine, I first have to invest 10 minutes to change all the color schemes to setup everything again.

Recently I moved my `dotfiles` to a `mercurial` repository; and now my `aliases`, `hgrc` and `vimrc` move with me as I go. However I would love to take my color profiles with me as well; is there a way I can get this done?

Comment: The part not answered in the other question is *too localized*. Just check `sudo opensnoop` while editing these preferences to find out where they're stored.